# Not sure how to declare a variable (in MIDIPortConnectSource) for use with other methods in a class

Tags: objective-c, midi

I am trying to use this in a class.

```
 OSStatus MIDIPortConnectSource(
                                   MIDIPortRef     port,
                                   MIDIEndpointRef source,
                                   void*           connRefCon)
```

I'm not sure what connRefCon should be declared as in the header file.  Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is for your use. It is passed to your `MIDIReadProc` to identify the source. If you don't need to identify the source you can set it to `NULL`.